# Custom profiling in Java

Tags: java, profiling

I want to profile a Java code programmatically in Java. I have searched the internet about tutorials but in vain. All that I've come across is how to profile a Java code using a third party application. It would be of great help if  you guys can suggest some profiling API in Java and how to use it.

Comment: What's the problem using VisualVM or Mission Control?

Comment: No way, and i don't see why not to use 3rd party libs?

Comment: Third party libs are acceptable but not third party GUI applications. I want to achieve this through API usage within the code itself, which I want to profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) has an API for profiling where the results are directly accessible from the API - no GUI required.

See the `api/samples/platform` example in the installation directory and the javadoc in `api/javadoc`.

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler.